# php only download first 1mb of a file

Tags: php

I'm using file_get_contents to get a remote file. My question is, is it possible to ask php to downlaod the first 1mb of a file rather than the whole file? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my knowledge you can not specify the number of MBs but you can do something like below.

```
<?php
// Read 14 characters starting from the 21st character
$section = file_get_contents('./people.txt', NULL, NULL, 20, 14);
var_dump($section);
?>
```

[Read Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
string file_get_contents ( string $filename [, bool $use_include_path
= false [, resource $context [, int $offset = -1 [, int $maxlen ]]]] )
```

> maxlen - Maximum length of data read. The default is to read until end
>   of file is reached. Note that this parameter is applied to the stream
>   processed by the filters.

Answer (score 3):

From php.net [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents)

```
string file_get_contents ( string $filename [, bool $use_include_path = false [, resource $context [, int $offset = -1 [, int $maxlen ]]]] )
```

You have to specify last `maxlen` parameter (in bytes).

> **maxlen**
>
> Maximum length of data read. The default is to read until end of file is reached. Note that this parameter is applied to the stream processed by the filters.